# Problem with executing .py script

Tags: python, scripts

I am a complete newbie in terms of using Ubuntu and I have stumbled upon this problem: I am trying to run this script: https://gist.github.com/mjkoo/0eb70888b6085b3f65f5 (it's basically a tool that renames all files into lowercase). I've tried using:

```
python eui_install.py
```

and

```
chmod +x eui_install.py
./eui_install.py
```

but everything I get back is:

```
Usage: eui_install.py [ZIPFILE]
```

The files in the designated folder still have names with uppercase. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You are forgetting to supply a mandatory argument.

```
 Usage: eui_install.py [ZIPFILE]
```

means you have to include a name of a zipfile. The command is:

```
python eui_install.py zipfile
```

where zipfile is a file name you need to supply (probably the mod you want to edit looking at the script).

> The files in the designated folder still have names with uppercase. What am I doing wrong?

Those files are what you need to add to the command (ie. 2nd argument is 1 zipped file).